# Scrapy extracting data from json response

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract data from a json response using `scrapy`. The aim is to get the products listed in the respons:e

```
import scrapy
import json

class DepopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'depop'
    allowed_domains = ["depop.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance']
def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    yield from data['meta']['products']
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Spider error processing <GET [https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1596&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>](https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1596&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance%3E) (referer: None)

Comment: hey mate, why do you need scrapy for it?

Comment: @y.y Trying to get into the practice of using scrapy above others. But also using scrapy for json response is new to me so I'm excited to learn how to do it properly.

Comment: okey i understand :) scrapy is really nice, but for me I would say its the wrong module to parse json requests, check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the minimal working code using `scrapy and json`

## Script:

```
import scrapy
import json

class DepopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'depop'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request (
            url='https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance',
            method='GET',
            callback = self.parse,
           
            )
    def parse(self, response):
        resp= response.json()['products']
        #print(resp)
        # json_data = json.dumps(resp)

        # with open('data.json','w') as f:
        #     f.write(json_data)

        for item in resp:
            yield {
                'Name': item['slug'],
                'price':item['price']['priceAmount']
                }
```

## Output:

```
{'Name': 'kicksbrothers-exclusive-genuine-blue-inc', 'price': '22.98'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'isabellaimogen-crew-clothing-full-length-slim', 'price': '8.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'elliewarwick97-vintage-anchor-blue-shirt-size', 'price': '5.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'elliewarwick97-vintage-anchor-blue-brand-1990s', 'price': '5.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'tommkent-high-waisted-vintage-jeans-washed', 'price': '24.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'megsharp-super-cute-flowery-anchor-blue', 'price': '10.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'moniulka2607-sweat-wear-for-man-shorts', 'price': '30.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'quynheu-free-uk-shipping-anchor-blue-07e1', 'price': '8.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'bradymonster-oversized-stone-washed-shirt-from', 'price': '14.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'bonebear-vintage-funky-mens-large-shirt', 'price': '9.99'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'katy_potaty-vintage-anchor-blue-mom-jeanstrousers', 'price': '20.00'}       
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'urielbongco-washed-up-denim-jacket-preloved', 'price': '10.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'reubz16--thick-thermal-heavy-t-shirt', 'price': '10.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'reubz16--vintage-egypt-tourist-tee', 'price': '16.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'kristoferjohnson-blue-harbour-mens-tailored-fit', 'price': '7.99'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'ravsonline-blue-willis-pure-indigo-cotton', 'price': '27.20'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
{'Name': 'shikhalamode-anchor-blue-low-rise-denim', 'price': '8.00'}
2021-12-20 20:37:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance>
```

.. so on

Comment: I have a question on item loaders; How would I implement this for responses? For example, assuming I've created a class for items. Then in your loop I create a loader using `loader = ItemLoader(DepopItem(), selector=item)`, how would I select for the data like `name` and `price`? I'm only used to getting `xpaths` this way. I'm guessing it's `loader.add_value(?????)`?

Comment: Sure! check out the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70424004/adding-loaders-to-json-response-with-scrapy

Comment: I will try  and I have somewhat skill on it and it may take time as I'm a bit busy and you also can try taking online help. Thanks

Comment: That's fine! I managed to work it out in the end. Thanks for your template!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to handle the response of a json request maybe try this:

```py
import requests

url = "https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

so your output is stuff like:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "resultCount": 20,
        "cursor": "MnwyMHwxNjQwMDA1ODc3",
        "hasMore": false,
        "totalCount": 20
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 215371070,
            "slug": "kicksbrothers-exclusive-genuine-blue-inc",
            "status": "ONSALE",
            "hasVideo": false,
            "price": {
                "priceAmount": "22.98",
                "currencyName": "GBP",
                "nationalShippingCost": "4.99",
                "internationalShippingCost": "10.00"
            },
            "preview": {
                "150": "https://pictures.depop.com/b0/24241961/1015682639_ea92c00979b64a298f7b9cce465bfb5f/P2.jpg",
                "210": "https://pictures.depop.com/b0/24241961/1015682639_ea92c00979b64a298f7b9cce465bfb5f/P4.jpg",
                "320": "https://pictures.depop.com/b0/24241961/1015682639_ea92c00979b64a298f7b9cce465bfb5f/P5.jpg",
                "480": "https://pictures.depop.com/b0/24241961/1015682639_ea92c00979b64a298f7b9cce465bfb5f/P6.jpg",
                "640": "https://pictures.depop.com/b0/24241961/1015682639_ea92c00979b64a298f7b9cce465bfb5f/P1.jpg",
                "960": "https://pictures.depop.com/b0/24241961/1015682639_ea92c00979b64a298f7b9cce465bfb5f/P7.jpg",
                "1280": "https://pictures.depop.com/b0/24241961/1015682639_ea92c00979b64a298f7b9cce465bfb5f/P8.jpg"
            },
            "variantSetId": 93,
            "variants": {
                "7": 1
            },
            "isLiked": false
        },
```

How to parse json response

```
import requests
import json

def get_requests():
    url = "https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance"
    payload={}
    headers = {}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.text

# x uses method "get_requests"
x = get_requests()

data_json = json.loads(x)
for id, price in zip(data_json['products'], data_json['products']):
    print(id['id'])
    print(price['price']['priceAmount'])
```

Output:

```
215371070
22.98
256715789
8.00
202721541
5.00
202722546
5.00
274328291
24.00
221641139
10.00
245419941
30.00
192541316
8.00
147762409
14.00
158406248
9.99
234693030
20.00
213377081
10.00
228630951
10.00
203627182
16.00
159958157
7.99
151413456
27.20
250985338
8.00
185488012
15.00
154423470
20.00
193888222
10.00
```

You looped through the json response and just saved the values of key: "id" and "price"

Comment: Ah I see! I probably need to include headers which is likely to fix the issue

Comment: Now have look at my edtied answer. Do you still miss few things? :)

Comment: OP Asked a question for Scrapy but the answer guiding the user to use requests! that's why i down-voted that answer!

Comment: alright so i should explain him the wrong way ? @Ahmed

Comment: He's right, I was only looking for a scrapy answer. Alternatively, perhaps you want to check out my other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70423056/loop-values-from-response-into-url . An answer with `requests` is welcomed!