# Loop values from response into url

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a loop on some response data from a website. The loop should effectively grab the value within the tag `cursor`, and read this into the url link and repeat this continuously until the last link has no tag `cursor`. The `cursor` tag has a value which gives info on the next url page that is loading.

I so far only get it to work individually likeso:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def ids(url):
    payload={}
    headers = {}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    test2 = []
    test= pd.read_json(StringIO(response.text), lines=True)
    for m in test['meta'].items():
        for j in m[1].values():
            test2.append([j])
    id = test2[1][0]

#split - the next part should repeat

    html = f'https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1596&cursor={id}&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance'
    r = requests.request("GET",html, headers=headers, data=payload)
    list_id = []
    read_id = pd.read_json(StringIO(r.text), lines=True)
    for m in read_id['meta'].items():
        for id in m[1].values():
            list_id.append([id])
    id2 = list_id[1][0]
    return id2
```

Then I try:

```
url = 'https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1645&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance'
ids(url)
```

However, I have to replicate the code below 'split' in such a way that it can just loop the new id (so id2) into the f-string for the html and keep extracting the value within `cursor` and store the values as a big list. My approach I can only grab them one-by-one, and will have to keep repeating the code above which will take an enormous amount of time and code. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Expected output:

```
['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDA4MjI2', 'M3w0OHwxNjQwMDA4MjI2', 'NnwxMjB8MTY0MDAwODIyNg', ...]
```

Ways it may work:

- Run the code within a while loop and have the f string take the last string in list id2, so that when the code iterates and produces a new id it then takes that latest id and so forth until the last 2 are equal we stop.

Aftering testing with a `while` loop it seems to work but I end up getting an error anyways:

```
def ids(url):
    payload={}
    headers = {}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    list_id=[]
    test= pd.read_json(StringIO(response.text), lines=True)
    for m in test['meta'].items():
        list_id.append(m[1]['cursor'])
    
    while True:
        html = f'https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands=1596&cursor={list_id[-1]}&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance'
        r = requests.request("GET",html, headers=headers, data=payload)
        read_id = pd.read_json(StringIO(r.text), lines=True)
        for m in read_id['meta'].items():
            try:
                list_id.append(m[1]['cursor'])
            except:
                continue
    
        if list_id[-2] == list_id[-1]:
            break
    
    return list_id
```

I get the following error right before the exception:

> KeyError: 'meta'

But it still grabs the data when I check the list, how can I make it so that no error appears?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Either provide all the info, or simplify it to only keep the relevant parts

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).